# Why is Maxima failing to give a solution?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I have a function in Maxima I am differentiating then attempting to find the value at which this is zero. When I use solve(), however, I am not given a solution. Why is this, and how can I work around it?

```
(%i1)   f(x):=(-5*(x^4+5*x^3-3*x))/(x^2+1);
(%o1)   f(x):=((-5)*(x^4+5*x^3+(-3)*x))/(x^2+1)
(%i2)   df(x):=''(diff(f(x), x));
(%o2)   df(x):=(10*x*(x^4+5*x^3-3*x))/(x^2+1)^2-(5*(4*x^3+15*x^2-3))/(x^2+1)
(%i3)   solve(df(x), x);
(%o3)   [0=2*x^5+5*x^4+4*x^3+18*x^2-3]
```

Answer (score 3):

The function `solve` is not too strong; there are many problems it can't solve. A stronger version is under development. In the meantime, try the add-on package `to_poly_solve`. Here's what I get:

```
(%i1) df(x) := (10*x*(x^4+5*x^3-3*x))/(x^2+1)^2-(5*(4*x^3+15*x^2-3))/(x^2+1) $

(%i2) load (to_poly_solve) $
(%i3) to_poly_solve (df(x), x);
(%o3) %union([x = - 2.872468527640942], [x = - 0.4194144025323134], 
[x = 0.3836388367122223], [x = 0.2041221431132173 - 1.789901606296292 %i], 
[x = 1.789901606296292 %i + 0.2041221431132173])
```

Something which is maybe a little surprising is that `to_poly_solve` has returned a numerical solution instead of exact or symbolic. Tracing `allroots` shows that `to_poly_solve` has constructed a quintic equation and punted it to `allroots`. Since the general quintic doesn't have a solution in terms of radicals, and even in special cases it's probably very messy, maybe it's most useful to have a numerical solution anyway.

Try `plot2d(df(x), [x, -3, 1])` to visualize the real roots returned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find a numerical solution. I don't know why `solve` does not try this. Either you take the ouput of `aolve`or you do hte folölowing:

```
(%i1) f(x):=(-5*(x^4+5*x^3-3*x))/(x^2+1);

                                      4      3
                              (- 5) (x  + 5 x  + (- 3) x)
(%o1)                 f(x) := ---------------------------
                                         2
                                        x  + 1
(%i2) df(x):=''(diff(f(x), x));

                            4      3                3       2
                     10 x (x  + 5 x  - 3 x)   5 (4 x  + 15 x  - 3)
(%o2)       df(x) := ---------------------- - --------------------
                             2     2                  2
                           (x  + 1)                  x  + 1
```

Bring it to a  common denominator and extract the numerator:

```
(%i3) xthru(df(x));

                   4      3              2          3       2
            10 x (x  + 5 x  - 3 x) - 5 (x  + 1) (4 x  + 15 x  - 3)
(%o3)       ------------------------------------------------------
                                    2     2
                                  (x  + 1)
(%i4) num(%);

                   4      3              2          3       2
(%o4)       10 x (x  + 5 x  - 3 x) - 5 (x  + 1) (4 x  + 15 x  - 3)
```

use `allsroots`to find the roots of a polynomial numerically

```
(%i5) allroots(%);

(%o5) [x = 0.3836388391066617, x = - 0.4194143906217701, 
x = 1.789901606296292 %i + 0.2041221431132174, 
x = 0.2041221431132174 - 1.789901606296292 %i, x = - 2.872468734711326]
```

skip the complex solutions

```
(%i6) sublist(%,lambda([t],imagpart(rhs(t))=0))
;

(%o6) [x = 0.3836388391066617, x = - 0.4194143906217701, 
                                                       x = - 2.872468734711326]
```